# Case insensitive query subscriber TypeORM

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

Since I'm new to subscriber in TypeORM, I asked chatgpt for help. It gave me the right thing but looks like it's too old since the methods like `beforeSelect` doesn't exist anymore in TypeORM.

I really need to make this work and I'm lost since I find nothing in the documentation or on web about this topic of case insensitive query subscriber with TypeORM.

I would like to know how to make this kind of code in 2023 for TypeORM / Typescript :

```js
import { EventSubscriber, EntitySubscriberInterface, SelectQueryBuilder } from "typeorm";

@EventSubscriber()
export class CaseInsensitiveQuerySubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
    beforeSelect(queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>): Promise<any> | void {
        this.applyCaseInsensitive(queryBuilder);
    }

    beforeUpdate(queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>): Promise<any> | void {
        this.applyCaseInsensitive(queryBuilder);
    }

    beforeRemove(queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>): Promise<any> | void {
        this.applyCaseInsensitive(queryBuilder);
    }

    private applyCaseInsensitive(queryBuilder: SelectQueryBuilder<any>): void {
        const parameters = queryBuilder.getParameters();
        for (const param in parameters) {
            const value = parameters[param];
            if (typeof value === "string") {
                const newParam = `${param}_iLIKE`;
                queryBuilder.setParameter(newParam, `%${value}%`);
                queryBuilder.andWhere(`${param} ILIKE :${newParam}`);
                queryBuilder.setParameter(param, undefined);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !